# Use of weights in choosing power parameter in Tweedie distribution

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, tweedie-distribution

I'm looking at the implementation of the `tweedie.profile` function from the R package `tweedie`. I have a few questions.
When trying to find the best power parameter $p$, by using the function `tweedie.profile` for example,

```
tweedie.profile(y ~ .,
                method = 'series',
                phi.method = 'mle'
                weights = w, 
                eps = 0,
                data = data)
```

Where `w` is a vector of weights used in the fitting the GLM. The code to obtain the MLE of $\phi$ is,

```
ans <- optimize(f = dtweedie.nlogl, maximum = FALSE, 
                interval = c(low.limit, 10 * phi.est), power = p, 
                mu = mu, y = ydata)
```

How come that the weights don't play any rule in the function? Shouldn't it be taken into account when computing $\hat{\phi}_{mle}$?

Here is a concrete example, it is well known that if the power parameter of tweedie $p = 0$ the distribution is Normal. Therefore, we can compare the appropriate GLM with the tweedie function.

```
 library(tweedie)
set.seed(1)
normal_y <- exp(rnorm(1000))
random_w <- runif(1000,0,10)

# No weights 
glm_model <- glm(normal_y ~ 1, family = gaussian("log"))
mle_full_tweedie <- tweedie.profile(
  normal_y ~ 1 ,
  p.vec = 0,
  offset = NULL,
  link.power = 0, # default is logarithmic link function
  do.smooth = FALSE,
  do.plot = FALSE,
  method = "series",
  verbose = 0,
  eps = 0
)


# With weights
glm_model_w <- glm(normal_y ~ 1, weights = random_w, family = gaussian("log"))
tweedie_model_w <- mle_full_tweedie <- tweedie.profile(
  normal_y ~ 1 ,
  weights = random_w,
  p.vec = 0,
  offset = NULL,
  link.power = 0, # default is logarithmic link function
  do.smooth = FALSE,
  do.plot = FALSE,
  method = "series",
  verbose = 0,
  eps = 0
)
```

Resulting with

```
> print(paste0('logLiklihood of Tweedie model (no weights):', mle_full_tweedie$L.max))
[1] "logLiklihood of Tweedie model (no weights):-2297.19437626455"
> print(paste0('logLiklihood of GLM model (no weights):', logLik(glm_model)))
[1] "logLiklihood of GLM model (no weights):-2297.09892399843"
> 
> print(paste0('logLiklihood of Tweedie model (weights):', tweedie_model_w$L.max))
[1] "logLiklihood of Tweedie model (weights):-2297.19437626455"
> print(paste0('logLiklihood of GLM model (weights):', logLik(glm_model_w)))
[1] "logLiklihood of GLM model (weights):-2439.90755930638".
```

Second, the function optimizes over the function `dtweedie.nlogl` which is a function that mixes the series and interpolation methods for estimating the likelihood. Why does it differ from the method set in the `tweedie.profile` function?

Comment: What weights are you referring to?

Comment: added an example

Comment: You might also want to add which package this is in; it's an easy internet search, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "How come that the weights don't play any rule in the function? Shouldn't it be taken into account when computing $\phi_{mle}$?".
2. "... the function optimizes over the function `dtweedie.nlogl` which is a function that mixes the series and interpolation methods for estimating the likelihood. Why does it differ from the method set in the `tweedie.profile` function?"

To answer 1: Yes, the weights *should* come into play in the estimation of $\phi_{mle}$ (as you demonstrate). This is an error (and feel free to send through a fix :->).

To answer 2: The documentation specifies that `phi.method` is 'one of "saddlepoint" or "mle"'... the options do not include `series` or `inversion` as implied.

Estimating the mle of $\phi$ is quite tricky, and sometimes mle fails... (hence the 'fallback' option of using the saddlepoint (mean deviance) estimate if the mle fails).

In the case `phi.method = "mle"`, the function tries its best to get an estimate... using any means it can find that works (series; inversion), and this cannot be user-specified (at present anyway).

Hope that helps.

P.